# Is it possible to make Azure Storage Blob Service Clients container-specific?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage

Currently I have an API that allows users to upload files to containers within my storage account. I want each of my clients to only be able to upload/access their own container.

I thought that I would be able to create a blob service client that limits access by container through creating a dynamic connection string. I was thinking the connection string would change depending on the user's assigned container as well as a SAS token I provide them with, but my current method is not working. Is it possible to have blob service clients that are container-specific?

The following is my code - I tried to follow the templates here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/api/connection-strings/storage-connection-strings for the connection string, however it is not working.

```
const connectionString = "https://<account>.blob.core.windows.net/" + <container> + "?" + <SASToken>;
const blobServiceClient = await BlobServiceClient.fromConnectionString(connectionString);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use [this constructor](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/storage/Azure.Storage.Blobs/src/BlobContainerClient.cs#:%7E:text=public%20BlobContainerClient(string%20connectionString%2C%20string%20blobContainerName)), depending on which version you are working with.

```
const blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString, containerName);
```

Comment: Sadly, this constructor does not work with my code. Something that I neglected to mention in my original post is that the next line of code after blobServiceClient is the following line: const blobServiceClient = await BlobServiceClient(connectionString, container); Would this not work with the constructor you answered with?

Comment: Have you tried copying the connection string from Azure Storage Account > Access Keys and Appending `;ContainerName=mycontainer` to it?
Please clarify which Azure library you are using. The one I mentioned works with Azure.Storage.Blobs.

Comment: Appending `;ContainerName=mycontainer` to the access key has worked for file uploads, however now when I generate an access key for a single container it can be used to access all containers within the account. Is there a way to append the access key to the connection string to limit access to other containers? Also, the Azure library I am using is @azure/storage-blob.